# Achieve same frequency of all characters of string in minimum operations. (All characters are from range 'a' to 'z')

Tags: c++

We need to find the minimum number of replacements needed to make the frequency of all characters equal in a given string ,where replacement means we can just replace any character of string by other character .

**ALL THE CHARACTERS SHOULD BE FROM RANGE 'a' to 'z'.

I found the frequency of all the characters in a string then sorted it to find the median , then calculated the cost required to achieve same frequecy by taking median as a reference.
I dont know where i am going wrong. Not the actual logic, but the slightest idea will be appreciated .

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long int min(int A[], long int n)
{
    long int cost = 0;
    sort(A, A + n);
    long int K = A[n / 2];
    for (long int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (A[i] - K)
            cost += abs(A[i] - K);
    }
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        long int tempcost = 0;
        K = A[(n / 2) - 1];
        for (long int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (A[i] - K)
                tempcost += abs(A[i] - K);
        }

        cost = min(cost, tempcost);
    }
    return cost;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        string s;
        cin >> s;

        long int arr[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }

        long int n = s.length();

        long int count = 0;
        for (long int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[s[i] - 'a']++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        int a[count], j = 0;

        for (long int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i]) {
                a[j++] = arr[i];
            }
        }

        cout << min(a, count) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected results : input : 1    aaaaabbbbccd 
                  output:  3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : I give a proposal at the end, but concerning the OP program :

> ALL THE CHARACTERS SHOULD BE FROM RANGE 'a' to 'z'

In *main*

```
arr[s[i] - 'A']++;
```

must be

```
arr[s[i] - 'a']++;
```

doing that change the execution is :

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

```
1
aab
1
```

---

```
    long int arr[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
```

can be just that :

```
    long int arr[26] = { 0 };
```

---

**A solution using the *brutal force***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isAsolution(const string & s)
{
  int count['z' - 'a' + 1] = { 0 };

  for (auto c : s)
    count[c - 'a'] += 1;

  string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
  int count0 = count[*it++ - 'a'];

  while (it != s.end())
    if (count[*it++ - 'a'] != count0)
      return false;

  return true;
}

void search(string & s, size_t pos, unsigned nChanges, unsigned & minChanges, string & sol)
{
  if (pos == s.length()) {
      // nChanges <  minChanges, useless to check
    if (isAsolution(s)) {
      minChanges = nChanges;
      sol = s;
    }
  }
  else if (nChanges < (minChanges - 1)) {
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c += 1) {
      // the string is modified to avoid a lot of copies
      char old = s[pos];

      s[pos] = c;
      search(s, pos + 1, (old == c) ? nChanges : (nChanges + 1), minChanges, sol);
      s[pos] = old;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc == 1) {
    cout << "Usage : " << *argv << " <string> ...  <string>" << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  while (*++argv) {
    string s = *argv;

    for (auto c : s) {
      if ((c < 'a') || (c > 'z')) {
        cout << "invalid input, chars must be between a and z" << endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }

    if (s.empty() || isAsolution(s))
      cout << s << " is already a solution" << endl;
    else {
      unsigned min = ~0u;
      string sol;

      search(s, 0, 0, min, sol);
      cout << min << " changes to do " << sol << " from " << s << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Rather than to read the number of string then to read them they are given in argument, is more practical

Example :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aab aze aaaaabbbbccd
1 changes to do aaa from aab
aze is already a solution
2 changes to do aaaacbbbbccc from aaaaabbbbccd
```

Under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out aab aze aaaaabbbbccd
==8364== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8364== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8364== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8364== Command: ./a.out aab aze aaaaabbbbccd
==8364== 
1 changes to do aaa from aab
aze is already a solution
2 changes to do aaaacbbbbccc from aaaaabbbbccd
==8364== 
==8364== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8364==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8364==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 21,248 bytes allocated
==8364== 
==8364== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8364== 
==8364== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8364== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

As you see for *aaaaabbbbccd* only 2 changes are needed, not 3 :-)

Comment: I have edited this but still it is not giving proper results for some cases as i edited in question

Comment: @vikashtiwari in your edition you missed to say to enter _1_ before the string

Comment: @vikashtiwari your two _for_ in _min_ compute the same value 6

Comment: yeah thats what the problem is , it should give 3 , there is some logical error , and i am asking for anyother suggestions to get the required results

Comment: Any other characters can be used regardless from the ones that are already used

Comment: No aab has a solution because you can just change 'a' to 'c'  So the solution will be 1 .. (We can change any character to anyother regardless it is present in string or not)

Comment: @vikashtiwari yes I suposed cannot use out of the already used char, but 
 there is no solution for a string having a length between 27 and 51 etc

Comment: There will always be a unique solution because in worst case you can just change all the characters to a common character and hence the worst case may be the no. of replacements in that case will be equal to length of string

Comment: @vikashtiwari ah yes, true. Your algorithm me is very far of that

Comment: Can you suggest a better approach ?

Comment: @vikashtiwari of course the _brutal force_ will find the solution, not sure there an heuristic to do shorter

Comment: Can you just explain a bit for the brutal solution , i could try to optimize it further then!Thanks

Comment: @vikashtiwari the _brutal_ solution basically look at all the possibilities or a little less without changing the complexity

Comment: @vikashtiwari I edited my answer with a proposal using the _brutal force_, and in fact the answer for _aaaaabbbbccd_ is not 3 but only 2

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time , Your code is clearly understandable !!